# How to cut decimal number using PHP

Tags: php, decimal, rounding

I have a code where I got some numbers like this:

```
92.682926829268
```

I'd like to cut them like this:

```
92.68
```

This is my code:

```
<td><?php if (($row['TotalMatch']) > 10){ echo ($row['OK_05'] / $row['TotalMatch']) * 100; }   ?></td>
```

**I tried with floor and round but I get that example I showed at the beginning of post ( 92.682926829268 instead of 92.68 )**

Thanks for your attention

Regards!

**EDIT** Could you give me an example with my code? Thanks

Comment: _round(92.682926829268, **2**);_ should be your friend

Comment: *but I don't get what I want* - Please elaborate. We can't read your mind.

Comment: Yes, what _do_ you get? The code in your question doesn't include floor or round. If you can show what you did with those functions, someone can tell you why it didn't get you the result you wanted.

Comment: I edited in bold and added an edit. I put at the begin what I wanted to get :)

Comment: Your edit does not show what you did with floor or round to get that number.

Comment: Because I get error, I don't know how I can apply floor in my code. just for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression you're trying to format is this:

```
($row['OK_05'] / $row['TotalMatch']) * 100
```

So whichever function you decide to use needs to go around that expression.

As to which function to use, you need to select one that returns a string, not a float.

If you use `round`, and your expression returns a float that rounds to a number with two zeros after the decimal point, the trailing zeros will not be displayed in the result. For example, `echo round(92.0006829268, 2)` will display `92`, *not* `92.00`. So don't use `round` if you need to be sure that two decimal places are always displayed. `round` is a math function, not a formatting function.

`floor` is really not useful at all here, as it returns a number with no decimal places.

---

A simple way is to use `sprintf` as shown in some of the other answers.

```
echo sprintf("%.2f", ($row['OK_05'] / $row['TotalMatch']) * 100);
```

The first argument to `sprintf` is `"%.2f"`, which is a format string indicating that the second argument should be displayed as a float with two decimal places. The second argument is your expression.

Using `bcdiv` as suggested in the other answer will also work, but it works a little differently that `sprintf` and will produce a slightly different result in some cases.

`sprintf` will round to the number of decimal places specified, so for example

```
echo sprintf("%.2f", 926.89 / 10);   // outputs 92.69
```

and `bcdiv` will truncate instead, so

```
echo bcdiv(926.89, 10, 2);           // outputs 92.68
```

Whichever one of those works for you, do that.

Comment: It's perfect, Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use `sprintf()` to format the number.

`echo sprintf("%.2f", 92.682926829268);`

Example: 
https://3v4l.org/U87T9

Comment: Could you show me in my example, please? because I don't know how I can insert it in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the round function

```
$var = 92.682926829268;
$var = round($var, 2)
```

Or use sprintf (`%.2f` cuts the number)

```
$var = sprintf("%.2f", $var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using sprintf like below:

```
<?php
$mynumber = 98.343434;
echo sprintf('%.2f', $mynumber);    // this will output 98.34
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`bcdiv()`](http://php.net/manual/function.bcdiv.php)

```
bcdiv($row['OK_05'], ($row['TotalMatch'] * 100), 2);
```